# Restrict the sharepoint access of sharepoint list member

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powerapps, developer-tools, power-platform

i m new to power platform.
i have created a PowerApps application that uses SharePoint lists as a database.
I use a form to take data from the PowerApps application and store it on a SharePoint list. This application will be utilized by everyone in the organization, so all end users of the application must be added to the SharePoint list as members in order to view the relevant data when filling out the form and storing it in the database.

However, as a member, they can view and edit the data. However, i do not want them to be able to modify the data directly in the SharePoint list.

if you can help with following alternatives -:

Not viewing the site in the SharePoint list. However, using the PowerApps application, it is possible to create data in the SharePoint List site.
can view the data and create the data in SharePoint List but, cannot modify the data of SharePoint list.
Restrict the user's access to redirect the SharePoint list through the MS team channel. – open in SharePoint web

i tried creating the permission by 
Setting -> Site Permissions -> Advance Permission Settings.

i created group with following permission -
List permission :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtX7D.png)

Site Permissions :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/718Gx.png)

However, users can still edit the data. I'm not sure if I set it up right.

i tried creating the permission by 
Setting -> Site Permissions -> Advance Permission Settings.

i created group with following permission -
List permission :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtX7D.png)

Site Permissions :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/718Gx.png)

However, users can still edit the data. I'm not sure if I set it up right.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proven method to achieve your goals.

Use a Power Automate flow to create the data in your SharePoint list. Use the 'Power Apps V2' trigger and call the flow from Power Apps when the form is submitted.

Then you can share the flow with your team as 'Run-only users'. This will allow you to also set up the flow to always use your SharePoint connection (and your permissions) instead of the user's permissions. This way, the user can be rid of all access to the SharePoint site and still be able to submit data.

Refer to these articles to achieve the solution:

[Run a flow from an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/using-logic-flows)

[Manage run-only users for a flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/manage-list-flows)